# How to toggle a DIV Container with pressing a JSF CommandButton?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsf

I have a div container like this in my xhtml page:

```
<div id="extendedOptions">
   <table>
      <tr> 
        <td>Some Text</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
   <h:outputText value="#{someResBundles}"
   <h:outputText value="#{someResBundles}"
</div>
```

Now i want to make this div container visible by clicking a jsf h:commandButton and not visible by clicking the h:commandButton again. I have declared this commandButton:

```
<h:commandButton id="extendedDiv" onclick="toggleDiv" />
```

toggleExtendedSearch is my js function:

```
function toggleDiv(){
   jQuery("#extendedOptions").toggle();
}
```

That works fine, but a have to questions:

How can set the div container as visible false?

Also i have a "a4j:poll", which rerendered an another section "Results" of my xhtml page any 20000 milliseconds and this closing and / or opening my div container "extendedOptions"

```
<a4j:poll interval="20000" action="#{bean.someActions}" ignoreDupResponses="true" reRender="Results" />
```

Comment: You can do `jQuery("#extendedOptions").hide()` in document ready, if you want to do with Jquery.

Comment: Your sugestions works fine. Do you have an idea, how i can work together with the a4j:poll? That will close my div section automatically, if it is opended / or visible in gui

Comment: I have no idea about that. Can you have any type of callback or something once the a4j:poll is rendered ?